Script to toggle pressure sensitivity
in photoshop, the brush tool allows the user to do straight lines holding shift and tapping various points.
what i'd like to do when shift is pressed is to also override/discard the pen pressure sensitivity of the wacom tablet so I get a hard line with no pressure.
basically like a mouse.
(I'm aware its possible to assign a keystroke to the "always use pressure for opacity" but I have tons of different tool presets with mixed flow/opacity settings that wouldn't work. I'd need the opposite override)
it doesn't seem there's a setting to do this in both wacom control panel or photoshop so I'm looking to see if this is achievable in any way like a JSX script to toggle the transfer on and off in the brush settings or an autohotkey script?
I tried things like
try {
    // Access the active document
    var doc = app.activeDocument;

    // Access the brush settings directly
    var brushSettings = doc.defaultBrushTool.brush;

    // Toggle the transfer checkbox
    brushSettings.useTransfer = !brushSettings.useTransfer;

    // Notify user (optional)
    alert("Transfer checkbox toggled!");
} catch (e) {
    alert("Error occurred: " + e);
}

but I get errors so not sure if possible.
and simulating mouse clicks on LButton presses in autohotkey fails to discard pressure information.
thanks for any input.
